# Flutter-Non-nullable instance field ‘{0}’ must be initialized error

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, non-nullable

I have created a seperate class "DirectionDetails" which is;

```
class DirectionDetails{

  int distanceValue;
  int durationValue;
  String distanceText;
  String durationText;
  String encodedPoints;

  DirectionDetails(this.distanceValue, this.durationValue, this.distanceText, this.durationText, this.encodedPoints);

}
```

When I try to initialize that in the main class by `DirectionDetails tripDirectionDetails;`, it gives the

> Non-nullable instance field 'tripDirectionDetails' must be initialized

error. But as it suggest, when I add "late" modifier - it dosen't show any errors **but when i run the app** it gives the,

> LateInitializationError: Field 'tripDirectionDetails' has not been
> initialized.

runtime error

There is an alternative method I tried, when i try to initialize `tripDirectionDetails` in main class using,

```
DirectionDetails tripDirectionDetails = new DirectionDetails();
```

and modify `DirectionDetails` class by,

```
class DirectionDetails{

  int distanceValue;
  int durationValue;
  String distanceText;
  String durationText;
  String encodedPoints;

  DirectionDetails({this.distanceValue = 0, this.durationValue = 0, this.distanceText = "", this.durationText = "", this.encodedPoints = ""});
  
}
```

App runs **successfully**, it retrieves all the vales in "DirectionDetails" class **only for the initial reboot.**

**But when I exit the app and come back, it gives the following error.**

> LateInitializationError: Field 'tripDirectionDetails' has not been
> initialized.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show where the `tripDirectionDetails ` is being used?

Comment: @JohnOyekanmi
Text(((tripDirectionDetails!= null) ? tripDirectionDetails.durationText : '') , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.grey),),

Comment: Okay, I assume the widget in which this is being used is a StatefulWidget.      
If that's the case try initializing the field, `tripDirectionDetails`, at the initState method before making use of it anywhere. Something like this `tripDirectionDetails  = DirectionDetails()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because you are trying to use `tripDirectionDetails` before initializing it. You should use `late` only for non null variables that will be initialized later before trying to use:

```
tripDirectionDetails != null /// This will trigger an error
```

You should initialize it before using it on `build` or in `initState`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    tripDirectionDetails = DirectionDetails();
    super.initState();
  }
```

But as `tripDirectionDetails` can be null, it would be better to declare it like this:

```
DirectionDetails? tripDirectionDetails;

tripDirectionDetails != null /// Won't trigger an error
```